# inline edit for the relational record in the lightning datatable

Tags: lightning-datatable, inline, edit, lightning-components

How can we make inline edit form features for relational record in the lightning datatable?

Below is the current code, and I would like to you to correct this code to achive inline edit for relational reocrd.

component

```
<lightning:datatable columns="{!v.columns}"
                             data="{!v.data}"
                             keyField="id"/>
```

Javascript

```
 var columns = [
            {label:'product code', fieldName:'prod_code', type:'STRING', editable:true},
            {label:'product name', fieldName:'prod_name', type:'STRING'}, editable:true},
            {label:'employee name', fieldName:'emp_name', type:'url', editable:true, typeAttributes:{label:{fieldName: "emp_name"}}}
 ];
//please assume that employee name is the relational record with a parent object.
//and other two records are the normal records.
component.set("v.columns", columns);

 var data = [
            {prod_code:"001K89", prod_name:"product A", emp_name:{Name:"employee A"}}
 ];
component.set("v.data", data);
```

By this code something like this picture is shown and cannot edit relational record.

[image]

I would like to make inline edit like attached.

[image]

Thnak you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you post your code, I can help you debug.

Otherwise,Salesforce provides documentation for inline editing  of data tables here:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:datatable/example#lightningcomponentdemo:exampleDatatableInlineEdit

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
Now I upload my code. I would like you to correct my code to do inline edit for relational reocrd.
Thank you.